# errorplacement default style

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-validate

I have created some pages jsp with the data entry form.
Some pages have defined the function validated:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#newPassword").validate({
        rules : {
            password : "required",
            passwordConfirm : {
            equalTo : "#password"
            }
        },
        messages : {
            passwordConfirm : "<spring:message code='change.label.error.confirmPassword'/>"
        }
    });
});
</script>
```

In this case the error is displayed in this way:

[image]

I would rather see it as is done by the default browser:

[image]

How can I do it?

Comment: [HTML5 validation](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/)

Comment: Not find what I'm looking for.

Comment: Then please better explain your exact problem.  The second picture is showing the HTML5 validation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "In this case the error is displayed in this way:"

[image]

That is how the jQuery Validate plugin creates the error messages.

---

> ".... as is done by the default browser:"

[image]

That is how the browser uses [HTML5 validation attributes to create the error messages](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/html/html5-form-validation/).

---

> "I would rather see it as is done by the default browser:  How can I do it?"

Remove the jQuery Validate plugin to allow the browser default (HTML5) to take over.  Otherwise, you cannot let the browser use HTML5 validation while using the jQuery Validate plugin, because the plugin dynamically disables any HTML5 validation and takes over.

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer.
Unknowingly I did as you say, that I removed jquery validate and I used a javascript function simply:
`function validatePass(p1, p2,text) {
 if (p1.value != p2.value || p1.value == '' || p2.value == '') {
  p2.setCustomValidity(text);
 } else {
  p2.setCustomValidity('');
 }
}`